# How do I get the tags a commit belongs to?

Tags: git, github-api

I have a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Brickbucket/test) and [a commit with an annotated tag](https://github.com/Brickbucket/test/commit/8dff1e64b5a28f8293debe2c7d5aeca7dd5ae2be). I can see [the tag](https://github.com/Brickbucket/test/tree/tagged-commit) fine from the web UI, but it doesn't seem to be exposed through the API, neither through the [commits API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) nor the [tags API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) (which from what I can tell only seems to handle going the other way: annotated tag to commit). Scraping the [refs API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) seems like an almost viable workaround, except for that it causes more and more traffic the more tags there are in the repository. Is there any other way?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @michas getting a list of tags that point to a certain commit (which I already know the hash of) without scraping all tags in the repo, as the title says

Answer (score 1):

```
git ls-remote git://github.com/antirez/redis.git | grep <SHA>
```

[`git-describe-remote.sh`](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/scripts/git-describe-remote.sh)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that only the tag known about its commit and the commit itself does not know about which tags are pointing to that commit. Hence, the only chance is iterating over all tags and checking whether they are pointing to the commit in question.

On a local repository you can use things like:

```
git log -1 --decorate $SHA1
```

For a remote repository you probably have to get all refs using `git ls-remote`.

If you want to use the API, probably [get-all-references](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-all-references) is the corresponding equivalent.
Especially `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/tags` will list you all tags.